# In python project,shows "attempted relative import with no known parent package File"

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, launch

**attempted relative import with no known parent package
File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\gordon\soccer\plugins\my_plugin.py", line 7, in

```
from  ..public.json.json import JsonCommMgr
```

ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package**

here's directory tree:
[image]

in json.py , there is defined  a class JsonCommMgr, and in my_plugin.py , I wanna use this class JsonCommMgr.
and in main.py , I used:

```
        try:
            plugin_module = importlib.import_module(f'plugins.{plugin_name}')
        ....
```

main.py only load plugin file my_plugin.py , and execute my_plugin.py's function named run

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577). Instead, format code as a [code block]. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.